# conda said all requested packages already installed but can't find in conda list

Tags: python, conda, snorkel

my device is M1 mac, I want to install Snorkel pkg, however, my conda said all requested packages already installed, but I can't find it in conda list and pycharm can't import ether.
Here is the log

```
sudo conda install snorkel
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

(works)  ~  conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/jhj/miniforge3/envs/works:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   0.12.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
aiohttp                   3.7.4            py38h30f7421_0    conda-forge
appnope                   0.1.2            py38h10201cd_1    conda-forge
astor                     0.8.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
astunparse                1.6.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
async-timeout             3.0.1                   py_1000    conda-forge
attrs                     21.2.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
blinker                   1.4                        py_1    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38h30f7421_1001    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.17.1               h27ca646_1    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2020.12.5            h4653dfc_0    conda-forge
cached-property           1.5.2                hd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
cached_property           1.5.2              pyha770c72_1    conda-forge
cachetools                4.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2020.12.5        py38h10201cd_1    conda-forge
cffi                      1.14.5           py38he62ddd7_0    conda-forge
chardet                   4.0.0            py38h10201cd_1    conda-forge
click                     8.0.1            py38h10201cd_0    conda-forge
cryptography              3.4.7            py38h3c0dae5_0    conda-forge
dataclasses               0.8                pyhc8e2a94_1    conda-forge
decorator                 5.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
gast                      0.4.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
google-auth               1.30.0             pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.1                      py_2    conda-forge
google-pasta              0.2.0              pyh8c360ce_0    conda-forge
grpcio                    1.37.1           py38h69ee544_0    conda-forge
h5py                      3.2.1           nompi_py38hb525b2d_100    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.6          nompi_h0fc092c_1114    conda-forge
idna                      2.10               pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        4.0.1            py38h10201cd_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.23.1           py38h2cb4d76_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.0           py38h10201cd_2    conda-forge
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
krb5                      1.19.1               hd92b7a7_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0                9_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0                9_openblas    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.76.1               h8fe1914_2    conda-forge
libcxx                    12.0.0               h168391b_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         hc8eb9b7_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 h642e427_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.3                  h9f76cd9_2    conda-forge
libgfortran               5.0.0.dev0      11_0_1_hf114ba7_22    conda-forge
libgfortran5              11.0.1.dev0         hf114ba7_22    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0                9_openblas    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.43.0               hf3018f0_0    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.15          openmp_hf330de4_1    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.17.0               hccf11d3_0    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.9.0                hb80f160_6    conda-forge
llvm-openmp               11.1.0               hf3c4609_1    conda-forge
markdown                  3.3.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
multidict                 5.1.0            py38h30f7421_1    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.2                  h9aa5885_4    conda-forge
numpy                     1.20.3           py38hbf7bb01_0    conda-forge
oauthlib                  3.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1k               h27ca646_0    conda-forge
opt_einsum                3.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pip                       20.2.4                     py_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.18             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.17.0           py38h6f2b01f_0    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pyasn1                    0.4.8                      py_0    conda-forge
pyasn1-modules            0.2.7                      py_0    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.20               pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pygments                  2.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyjwt                     2.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 20.0.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py38h10201cd_3    conda-forge
python                    3.8.10          hf9733c0_1_cpython    conda-forge
python-flatbuffers        2.0                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.8                      1_cp38    conda-forge
readline                  8.1                  hedafd6a_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.25.1             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
rsa                       4.7.2              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.6.3            py38hd0c9ec0_0    conda-forge
setuptools                49.6.0           py38h10201cd_3    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.35.5               hc49ca36_0    conda-forge
tensorboard               2.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.0              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
tensorflow-estimator      2.4.0              pyh9656e83_0    conda-forge
termcolor                 1.1.0                      py_2    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.10               hf7e6567_1    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.0.5                      py_0    conda-forge
typeguard                 2.12.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         3.7.4.3                       0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         3.7.4.3                    py_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.4             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
werkzeug                  2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.12.1           py38h30f7421_3    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                h642e427_1    conda-forge
yarl                      1.6.3            py38h30f7421_1    conda-forge
zipp                      3.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h31e879b_1009    conda-forge
(works)  ~ 
```

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`? That is usually a sign of misconfigured Conda installation.

Comment: Thanks for ur edit. I used sudo cuz my anaconda is in my system path. If I don’t use it, anaconda couldn’t download files.

Comment: But the `works` environment is in the user path, which should be writable without sudo. Try installing there without sudo.

Comment: Either use `sudo` in both calls, or in neither one. It changes environment variables, so you don't know that `sudo conda` and `conda` are even talking about the same copy of conda / the same Python installation.